# Irregular behaviour of MySQL search

Tags: php, mysql

Sometimes there is a match and sometimes not; even if I copy a value straight from the database, it is not always found.

This is the code:

```
if (isset($_POST['name_query'])){
    $_name=$_POST['name_query'];
    $new_name=filter_var($_name, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $sql="SELECT  client_id, id_num, name, surname FROM clients
          WHERE name = ' $new_name' " ;
    //$new_string = filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //-run  the query against the mysql query function 
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    //error handling
    if($result === FALSE) { 
        die(mysql_error()); 
    }
    echo "<tr>", "</td>","<td>","<h2 style='color:red'>Search Results</h2>","</td>","</tr>";    
    //-create  while loop and loop through result set 
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        $id4= $row['client_id'];
        $id_num=$row['id_num']; 
        $name=$row['name']; 
        $surname=$row['surname'];   

        //-display the result of the array............ trim($str,"Hed!");
        if ( $name != '') {
            echo "<tr>", "<td>", 
                 "<a  href=\"display_row.php?client_id=$id4 \">",
                 $id_num, "   " , $name , "    ", $surname,"</a>",
                 "</td>","</tr>";
        }
    }                
}
```

Comment: mysql_* function have been deprecated  you should be using mysqli or pdo for db access.

Comment: do you get 0 rows or do you get an error ? nothing seems "random" here...

Comment: might also be a good idea to remove the leading space before your variable in the query string and trim off whitespace from the input

Comment: @Orangepill yes I have noticed that if I put a leading space in the actual database field it get matched. So how do I remove the leading space from my form input field

Comment: You do not put the extra space in the PHP code, and use trim() on the _POST value.

Comment: to make leading and trailing the whitespace irrelevent call trim on both sides of the = in your query.. i.e.    trim(fieldname) = trim(' value')

Comment: @Orangepill thanx a lot it works now

Answer (score 0):

You have a redundant whitespace in your value (`' $new_name'`). You should

```
$sql="SELECT client_id, id_num, name, surname FROM clients WHERE name = '$new_name';
```

Mandatory comment:
Using string replacement in SQL queries is a bad practice that leaves your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Please consider using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: Thanks @Mureinik Pliz provide if you can an example of preparing the above statement